# Cookies set by a javascript

Tags: javascript, url, cookies, set

Is it possible to get details of cookies that are SET by the javascript sent by a particular URL? 
How can I do it?

For example, there is a URL www.abc.com and I want to know if this URL sends any ajavascript to run on computer to set any cookies. And if it sets any cookies which are those cookies?

Comment: Which details? Get them how (with JS, on serverside, for debugging in the browser)?

Comment: in javascript or in the browser console you can get the cookies using `document.cookie` or `document.cookie.split('; ');`

Comment: I cannot use browser functionalities. I have around 1000 URLs and need to find cookies set by the javascripts (if) sent by those URLs

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers let you view all cookies set by all sites, for example in Firefox:

```
Tools -> Options -> Privacy tab -> remove individual cookies
```